# Detecting mouse movement for a 3D first person world in Java

Tags: java, mouseevent, awtrobot

I am working on a first person game in Java, and I am trying to get the 3D movement working.

My problem is I would like to capture mouse movement, yet keep the mouse inside the window.  After I capture the mouse movement, I figure the best way to keep the mouse in my window is to center the mouse in the window after moving, using Robot.moveMouse(x,y).  This works fine, however the movement from the Robot triggers an event in my window which then gets interpreted as a normal event, and thus moves my character in the world.

I've tried various schemes of keeping state and ignoring movements until I am in the center, but they all seem finicky and don't quite detect which events are user vs Robot controlled.

Is there an easy way to detect that a mouse movement came from the Robot?

Is there perhaps a simpler way to solve my problem that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by switching to NEWT with JOGL 2.0 RC4.  In particular, I use GLWindow and warpPointer instead of an AWT Frame with the Robot.mouseMove.  With the switch, I instantly got smooth movements.  Some sample code similar to what I'm doing (mileage may vary):

```
public class MyClass implements MouseListener {
    private GLWindow window;
    private int centeredX = -1;
    private int centeredY = -1;

    // ...

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if (centeredX == -1 || centeredY == -1) {
            center();
            return;
        }

        int deltaX = e.getX() - centeredX;
        int deltaY = e.getY() - centeredY;

        // ... Do something with the deltas

        centeredX = window.getWidth() / 2;
        centeredY = window.getHeight() / 2;
        window.warpPointer(centeredX, centeredY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not 100% about this, but have you used the `getsource()` or `getComponent()` functions on your mouse event? They may return the robot as the source of it. Barring that, I would have a class variable like `boolean robotControlling` and anytime it takes control of the mouse, set that to true. Then, in you mouseListener, do a `if(!robotControlling){...}`. Hope this helps.

EDIT: if you have unused mouse buttons in your application (Java has Button 1, Button 2 and Button 3), you could make the robot press that, and in your mouse listener ignore any events with that code pressed. (use `evt.getButton()` for this) Of course, thats not exactly the cleanest solution :P

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately getSource returns where the event is happening (and I suspect getComponent is similar).  I've tried setting state like you describe, but it doesn't seem to be reliable and ends up with odd behavior. I've even tried using something like you describe with pressing buttons, and that still ended with unreliable behavior.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong with those approaches, but I seem to get mixed events of robot vs human and I end up ignoring events I shouldn't and vice versa.

Comment: Another note, I do something like you say of robotControlling, and then set it false to after my call to Robot.mouseMove, and it is always false inside the event (I'm sure the robot doesn't trigger the actual event until after I release control of the thread or something)

Comment: Well, what about setting it to true when you do the `mouseMove()` and then in the mouse listener adding `if(robotControlling && MOUSE CENTERED)robotControlling = false;` Effectively, make sure to wait until the mouse is centered before releasing the "lock"?

Comment: That's the solution I've finally ended up on, but it's still imperfect... from trying it out, I'm finding I get user mouse events before the centered mouse events, yet moved from as if the mouse had already been centered. Quite odd... and it seems if I don't recenter after such cases, I never get an actual centered event, so I get stuck no longer centering. I may have to just look at the next event and if it is off center, calculate the delta as if it were already centered rather than the last known spot.

Comment: Note: I say it is imperfect because the problems I described in my last comment have caused the movement to look jerky and unnatural, so as is, it is a poor solution, though somewhat functional.

Comment: Well, you could also start taking into account the direction of the mouse movements, whether they are towards the center or not, etc. It's unfortunate that java doesnt have a simply way to distinguish the events (as far as I can tell.)